# Move data-bound shape programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a project that involves clients (using mobile apps) wandering around an area and a server to which clients are reporting their live locations.  The server displays a map (custom to the venue; built via metadata) of the area, along with each client's current position.  I have the (static) map successfully being drawn via data-bound/ItemSourced shapes.  I can draw clients in the same way, but I'm not sure how to move them around on the screen.

Is there a proper/easy way to do this, or will I have to delete the old shape and recreate it each time?  Sorry for the lack of detail/proper diction; I'm very new to WPF.

Comment: For concept questions please post on Programmers Exchange. Stack Overflow is meant for code questions. For example: You have code you know is broke for some reason but don't know why. You post the code, the exception and what you have tried. People come in here, up vote your question, then hopefully post a mix of useful information and snark. Good luck my friend!

Comment: I'm well-familiar with both, but this is an implementation question, not a process/culture/professionalism question like most in PEx.  I'm asking how one does this in WPF, since I've only ever worked with direct-draw graphics stacks before, which require redrawing everything for each frame.

Comment: I understand what you are asking and I am trying to politely tell you that you are lacking fundamentals of a stack overflow question. Please add what you have tried, your current code and the expected outcome.

Comment: Besides the discussion, the answer is yes, WPF allows to move objects relative to their containers. There are however quite a few ways to achieve this, starting from the most basic `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties. I would however suggest to use a map control library, which should have some kind of `Location` property containing world coordinates, e.g. latitude and longitude.